# How to show list of names according to their rank in by using subject name as a drop down list excel

Tags: excel

Have some list of student name, their subject name and mark. If select the Subject name need to show list student name in descending order according to their mark rank
As shown in picture

[image]

Comment: Use a pivot table, with subject as the filter, and sort descending by Mark for student name

Comment: i need it by formula , because the subject name will be linked to some other sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you have to use formula, this one should work for you:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$3:C$13,SMALL(IF(($B$3:$B$13=$B$16),--($B$3:$B$13=$B$16)*(ROW($C$3:$C$13)-ROW($C$2)),""),ROW(B17)-ROW($B$16))),"")
```

This is an **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together inside formula bar), please enter this from `cell C17` and drag it over to column D and down for, maybe, 10 rows or depends on the maximum output of your data.

But there is a second way you can do which is easier.  Just leave the cursor on `cell B2` and go to `Data > Sort & Filter > and click Filter icon`, you can now do filters quickly like the pic below.

[image]

Either way, please try and let me know.